# subString by a string in PHP

Tags: php, substring

```
$element['path'] = "C:\xampp\htdocs\IntelliKid\public\assets\uploads\123.mp4";
```

As laravel 5 doesn't allow to access local files, I need to substring the above file path from assests folder to the end.

expected output `assets\uploads\123.mp4`

Also I want to take the format to another string.

expected output `.mp4`

Comment: Get the substrings start position from the original string. If you have to break it from assets, get its position using stripos (). Use the substr function then, and assign the start position to whatever stripos returned.

Comment: @crazyninja any reason not using Laravel path helpers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the document root:

```
$path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $element['path']);
```

`pathinfo()` can get the extension:

```
$ext  = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Or use `strstr()` and `strrchr()`:

```
$path = strstr($element['path'], 'assets');
$ext  = strrchr($element['path'], '.');
```

Though I would use `pathinfo()` for the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$asset_posn = strpos($element['path'],"assets\");
$output = substr($element['path'],$asset_posn);
$output1 = substr($element['path'],-4);
?>
```